# Div strangely shown at the top with Tablesorter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm using http://tablesorter.com/docs/ to try to sort a table. It works with a cosmetic issue that is not so much disturbing. The "zebra" doesn't activate until you really try to order the table. Isn't annoying at all but I couldn't find why this happens.

My really problem is that I'm trying to use also the pager plugin. The pager div appears at the top of the page. It may be caused (both problems) because I have the table inside a prior hidden tab the first time it appears. The content is loaded from a PHP file via AJAX and, when loaded, depending on the data, I could active tabs and tablesorter (or not).
If I do that, I do with this lines of code:

```
(".tab_content").hide();
                            $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
                            $(".tab_content:first").show();

                            $("#calls").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
```

The "pager" div is inside the tab, just below the target table.

As @mu is to shoort stated pager needs to know where the table is.

Tabs are loaded with

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#cont-standard-report">Standard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cont-extensions-report">Extensions</a></li>
    <li><a id="calls" href="#cont-calling-report">Callings</a></li>
</ul>
```

So, I tried with the proposed function but it even doesn't call it when clicking the tab.

```
$("#cont-calling-report").one('click', function() {
    alert ("Test");
    $("#calls").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
               .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
});
```

This is what happens. No click needed.

[image: http://imgur.com/CJnYX]

Managed to solve with this

Managed to solve it with this:

```
if (activeTab == '#cont-callings-report' && !tablesorter){
                                    $("#calls").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
                                    tablesorter = 1;
                                }
```

Inside the tab function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pager plugin probably needs to know where the table is and how big the table is before it can properly position itself. When your tab is hidden, the table inside it doesn't have a useful position so the pager probably ends up with zeros for the position it needs and the result is the pager at the top of the page. The easiest solution would be to bind `tablesorter` when the tab is clicked:

```
$(selector_for_the_tab_with_the_table).one('click', function() {
    $("#calls")
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
});
```

You only need to bind it once so use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

> This method is identical to [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind), except that the handler is unbound after its first invocation.

Comment: Hi, what you propose seems to be in the right direction, that's something I didn't thought but, it seems that it's not calling the function...

Comment: @Antonio: Are you using the right thing in place of "selector_for_the_tab_with_the_table"? I don't know what your HTML looks like so I used a placeholder.

Comment: @Antonio: Just making sure :) Try binding the `.one()` to the `<li>` rather than the `<a>`. The tabs are probably binding handlers to the list elements and those would prevent the click from getting down to the `<a>`.

Comment: Ok, I'm a jerk. I was binding to a ID field which wasn't present. Once I add the id to the li or to the add it calls the function but happens two things: 1.- It doesn't show anything 2.- The tab itself doesn't show properly.

Comment: @Antonio: I was looking at the `href` too, didn't even notice the lack of an `id`. Which tabs plugin are you using? Any chance that you could set up a demo on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Managed to solve it with this:

if (activeTab == '#cont-callings-report' && !tablesorter){
         $("#calls").tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}).tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
         tablesorter = 1;
        }

Inside the tab function.

Comment: @Antonio: Cool, that has the same effect as the `.one()` solution without confusing your existing JavaScript.